# CSS box-shadow shows weird white region?

Tags: shadow, css

The following code works fine for all my images, however, when I am using it on a **html5 canvas container** it shows a weird white region before the actual shadow.

CSS:

```
#container{
    width: 500px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

RESULT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8NYv.png

---

Does anyone know how to fix this? I've taken the original code from http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Comment: check in here..http://jsfiddle.net/tFUPU/ .. remove the shadow and see... you will get the clear image

Comment: @Ganesh I want to keep the shadow but I don't want to keep the weird white space in between.

Comment: Then you have to change the width of the container... you have to set the width and height to your own image size.. Hope it works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens so because images are inline by default. If you add `display: block;` to it - the white space will disappear. Like so (http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/tFUPU/2/

```
#container img {
    display: block;
}
```